# Paginator not generating links

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I'm stuck on this... Here's my code:

```
private function moderators () {
    $this->loadModel('Moderator');
    $this->Moderator->Behaviors->load('Containable');
    $this->Paginator = $this->Components->load('Paginator');
    $this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'contain' => array(
            'ModeratorPersonalData' => array(
                'conditions' => array('language' => $this->params['language']),
            ),
            'Thumb',
            'Image',
        ),
        'limit' => 1,
        'conditions' => array('role' => 'moderator'),
    );
    $moderators = $this->Paginator->paginate('Moderator');
    $this->set('moderators', $moderators);
}
```

The pagination works, when I type the url for page 2 manually it takes me there, but it isn't showing clickable links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did use Paginator helper in your view file, did't you?
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#PaginatorHelper

Comment: I feel so dumb now... :)